# cryptoapi windows 7 support

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-server-2008, cryptoapi, mscapi

Microsoft has introduced cryptography next generation [(CNG)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376210%28VS.85%29.aspx) from Vista and server 2008 onwards. But my question is to know **whether Microsoft supports the old [MS CAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (say for eg. in windows 2003 and windows xp) in Windows 7 and Server 2008**.

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean if Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 CryptoAPI is backwards compatible with older versions of CryptoAPI then yes.

All new CNG functionality is of course not.

Comment: I am sure that windows 7 and server 2008 has got CNG which is backward compatible with older version  - cryptoAPI; My question question is whether windows-7 supports the older - cryptoAPI?

Comment: As stated. The CryptoAPI in Win7 is backwardscompatible with the cryptoAPI in WinXP, etc. The CNG in Win7s CryptoAPI is NOT backwardscompatible with the CryptoAPI in WinXP, etc. since there is no CNG in those operating systems CryptoAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Windows 7 provides both APIs: CNG and CAPI.

Nevertheless, just try with verfy context:

```c
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = NULL;  
    if(CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_FULL,CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))                     
    {
        printf("CryptoAPI working\n\n");
        exit(0);    
    }else
    {
        printf("Error 0x%.8x",GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
}
```